# DOS Batch Script

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file

I'm trying to automate my build process using a DOS batch script. It works fine when I type the following into the command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Texas Instruments\ccsv4\eclipse\jre\bin\java" -jar "C:\Program File
s (x86)\Texas Instruments\ccsv4\eclipse\startup.jar" -data "C:\work\cwang\test_build" -app
lication com.ti.ccstudio.apps.projectBuild -ccs.projects M2_EVM6472 -ccs.configuration
Debug
```

But when I throw it into the batch script with all the necessary escape characters:

```
"C:\\Program Files ^(86^)\\Texas Instruments\\ccsv4\\eclipse\\jre\\bin\\java" -jar "C:\\Pro
gram Files ^(86^)\\Texas Instruments\\ccsv4\\eclipse\\startup.jar" -data "C:\\work\\cwang\
\test_build" -application com.ti.ccstudio.apps.projectBuild -ccs.projects M2_EVM6472 -ccs.
configuration Debug
```

I run into the following error:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

I'm new to batch scripting so I'm wondering if there's something fundamental I've overlooked.

Comment: I did not forget to replace "\" with "\\" in the actual batch script. Problem still stands.

Comment: Have you tried not to escape it? Because you really don't need this. Also, the .exe in java.exe is missing, it might be a problem.

Comment: Do you run this batch from Java application or from the command prompt?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and learn what [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) is!

Comment: @PM77-1 - I ran this from the command prompt

Comment: DOS batch scripting does not require escaping characters. Just make sure that any part that have spaces inside names is between quote marks.  Basically, whatever works from command prompt - should work in a batch file, assuming they are run from the same directory.

Comment: I see, I tried not escaping just now and it works. Which is strange considering the reason I started escaping was cause the un-escaped command didn't work the first time around. I think this might have just been an arduous process of fixing a typo. Thanks for helping guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know the issue:

```
"C:\\Program Files (86)\\Texas Instruments\\ccsv4\\eclipse\\jre\\bin\\java" -jar "C:/Program Files (86)/Texas Instruments/ccsv4/eclipse/startup.jar" -data "C:/work/cwang/test_build" -application com.ti.ccstudio.apps.projectBuild -ccs.projects M2_EVM6472 -ccs.configuration Debug
```

What additionally you should check:

1. make sure the directories are existing.
2. Check spaces between the directory names.

Please let me know the error, if any with above syntax?